# Search data in DB with CoreData and swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm a new in swift and CoreData and I have a problem:

1. I have DB with 2 columns: "name" and "number", for example
   name   number
   Bob      2
   Helena   5
   Helga    1
   Matilda  0
2. I connect my UITableViewController with DB across CoreData and it's working (i see all DB in my simulator of iphone)
3. I want find with swift in my DB cells of column "number" with value, for example, "1" and "2" and show proper cell from column "name" and as result I want to see:
   Bob    2
   Helga  1

How better to do it? I tried to work with NSPredicate, but I don't understand how it works and how to do so that it will be worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Add below function in your NSManagedObject extension

1) fetch data from coredata by id using predict

```
class func Search(PredictName:String, Uid:String, entityDescription: String,managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext) -> [AnyObject]? 
{
    var ar:[AnyObject] = []
    do
    {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(PredictName) == %@", Uid)
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityDescription)
                   request.predicate = predicate
         let result = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
                    ar = result
                }
                catch(_)
                {
                    ar = []
                }
                return ar as [AnyObject]
            }

Function Call :
var lists:[ModelClassName]?  = AdvertisementDataList.findByTypeInContext("user_id", url: self.Uid, entityDescription: "CoredataEntityName") as? [AdvertisementDataList]
```

It will return you predict column name data by row id

2) fetch all the data from coredata

```
class func Search(PredictName:String, entityDescription: String,managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext) -> [AnyObject]?
        {
            var ar:[AnyObject] = []
            do
            {
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(PredictName)")
                let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityDescription)
                request.predicate = predicate
                let result = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
                ar = result
            }
            catch(_)
            {
                ar = []
            }
            return ar as [AnyObject]
        }
```

Function Call :

```
var lists:[ModelClassName]?  = AdvertisementDataList.findByTypeInContext("user_id", entityDescription: "CoredataEntityName") as? [AdvertisementDataList]
```

It will return all the data by predict name.